# Which preposition is correct?- I will be back by/on Monday

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct out of the following & why?

> I will be back on Monday.
>
> I will be back by Monday.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct but they mean different things.

To be back **by Monday** means not later than Monday but it could be Saturday or Sunday or any other day previous to Monday.

To be back **on Monday** means on that day and not before or after.

As to **why** it's because that's what the prepositions signify.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, both of them are correct. However, there is a slight difference in meaning and usage.

In this sentence:

> I will be back **on** Monday.

you mean you will come back exactly on Monday, not before.

In this sentence:

> I will be back **by** Monday.

you mean that you will come back on or **before** Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. "I will be back on Monday" means "Monday is the day I will come back"; "I will be back by Monday" means "I will come back no later than Monday".

> On
>
> 8 Indicating the day or part of a day during which an event takes
>   place.
>
> ‘reported on September 26’
>   ‘on a very hot evening in July’

[On (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on)

> By
>
> 4 Indicating a deadline or the end of a particular time period.
>
> ‘I've got to do this report by Monday’
>    ‘by now Kelly needed extensive
>   physiotherapy’

[By (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)